# i am having a lag in updating data in mongodb using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

here's my code

```
 Datas.findOneAndUpdate({"_id":req.body._id}, Update(req.body))
         .then((data)=>{
                 res.json({data})
               })
```

my db gets updated on next updation query comes,that is i always have 1 query lag,**it is actually getting updated but it show the updated result on next query**,why is it so,is it because i called a function update?

```
function Update(n){
  let filter={};
if(n.issue_title!=""){filter.issue_title=n.issue_title}
if(n.issue_text!=""){filter.issue_text=n.issue_text}
if(n.created_by!=""){filter.created_by=n.created_by}
if(n.assigned_to!=""){filter.assigned_to=n.assigned_to}
if(n.status_text!=""){filter.status_text=n.status_text}
console.log("filter"+JSON.stringify(filter))
return filter;
}
```

**is that lagging because of calling a function** ,how can i solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the {new:true} object after your update object.

```
Datas.findOneAndUpdate({"_id":req.body._id},update_query, {new:true})
         .then((data)=>{
                 res.json({data})
               })
```